# Asymptotic states in strongly-coupled QFTs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, interactions, s-matrix-theory, strong-correlated

In QFT the asymptotic states play a very important role, as they are the basis on which we decompose our in-states and out-states when we calculate correlation functions.

However, I have not been able to find a good description that accommodates QFTs at arbitrary coupling. Most definitions assume that the theory is in the weakly-coupled regime and thus the asymptotic states must be the eigenstates of the effective Hamiltonian obtained when we set the interaction to zero, that is, the Hamiltonian of the free theory. Nonetheless, this is clearly not the case in a strongly-coupled QFT, for example in QCD, where the asymptotic states are hadronic particles that look nothing like the free quarks. If I understand correctly, "turning all interactions to zero" in a theory at strong-coupling like this would only make sense when dealing with an Effective Field Theory, which in turn uses the asymptotic states as fundamental degrees of freedom, so trying to find the correct way to turn the interactions off basically amounts to finding the asymptotic states directly.

In that sense I would like to find a more general definition for these states, and according to my understanding I suspect that they could maybe be defined as approximate eigenstates of the Hamiltonian in a certain suitable limit, but I am not sure which one.

Maybe they are the approximate eigenstates of H when other fields are substituted by their vacuum expectation values? In that case, given a Hamiltonian with $n$ fundamental degrees of freedom, would the asymptotic states be the eigenstates of all the possible effective Hamiltonians? That is, those Hamiltonians in which one of the fields is substituted by its v.e.v., those with two substitutions, and so on up to $n-1$ substitutions? (so we would have $n!$ possibly different effective Hamiltonians)

This is the definition that sounds most reasonable to me, but I suspect many of those effective Hamiltonians would be unstable or non-renormalizable, so I do not know if that could present difficulties. Furthermore, I cannot tell if this prescription would exhaust all asymptotic states or not.

I guess this is a complex problem, as one of its particular cases would consist on finding all possible hadronic states as suitable limits of the QCD Hamiltonian. But is the process just hard or straight-forward unknown?